# Any good alternatives to MediaWiki for creating an 'intranet' type system?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mediawiki, intranet

I would like to install some form of intranet system to allow multiple users to add documentation to - MediaWiki would suffice, I just wondered if anyone knew of any better alternatives (must be PHP).

Comment: Any CMS or blog platform with multiple user support would suffice. There are literally hundreds. This is not a programming question, it's off topic for StackOverflow, and it's a type of question listed in the FAQ under "questions NOT to ask here".

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? "Intranet" systems do often include wiki functionality but usually also a lot more, eg. [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/). If you're looking for *just* a wiki, you might want to modify your question and have a look around the stuff already tagged [tag:wiki]. Or if something more like Confluence, then some more requirements would be informative.

Comment: Why doesn't Mediawiki fit your needs?

Comment: If this were asked today it would be closed as off-topic because it is looking for software recommendations.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suggest you run through the [Wiki Choice Wizard](http://www.wikimatrix.org/wizard.php) over at WikiMatrix.org

Answer (score 2):

DokuWiki http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki

It has user authentication built in to prevent unauthorized access.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are *NO* good alternatives to mediawiki other than Wordpress, another open source platform.   Both have many extensions and are guaranteed to stick around for a very long time, probably forever.  Here's an example of a simple intranet based on Wordpress (which I haven't used and don't recommend except as a guide to features) http://www.simpleintranet.org/?gclid=CJ_c7erQsbUCFa9aMgoduWsAug

Using anything that is not open source and heavily used for open content is asking for lots of downstream problems.

Do not be fooled by these "better" or newer or "more supported" wikis, they are all fly by night and will all be effectively gone in five years.  Nothing protects you from some massive shift in underlying data structure even in something like Mindtouch which uses mediawiki as its base.  You find lots of good information on how to customize mediawiki, e.g. http://lifehacker.com/5396832/customize-mediawiki-into-your-ultimate-collaborative-web-site

Other open source alternatives like tikiwiki had promise but simply aren't widely used and will either disappear or become front ends for the data standards set by mediawiki.

Comment: -1 this answer is insane! there's no "forever" in software, even "guaranteed to stick around for a very long time" is too hard to say. I won't even also talk about the Dualism of open source x payed softwares..

Comment: -1 This is so anti-wiki. Pro-mediawiki. "Do not be fooled by" this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Many testimonials are available from major mediawiki users 
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_testimonials

Now here's a particularly challenging application I doubt you'll be seeing on Confluence
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellipedia

Comment: Whalecum to the scene and good answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have used MediaWiki for about two years in the previous company, and had so much trouble with it. The notation is cumbersome, weak search engine, and pages have no clear hierarchy.

If you can afford a paid product, you should seriously consider looking into [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence). If you require PHP, MySQL with a strong search engine consider having a look at [LessonsLearnedServer](http://www.lessonslearnedserver.com). The application is easy to use, good quality and has a decent pricing scheme.

If you insist on free, my best experience was with [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/). Although, you have to check what specific needs you require and check if they are provided by plugins.